# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error when using Java RSA encryption

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to set up RSA encryption so I can make a simple library for myself to use in the future and I can't get this simple code to work. Here is the source code:

```
package rsa.testing;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class AloneTest
{
    public static void doTest()
    {
        try
        {
            KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            gen.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair pair = gen.genKeyPair();
            System.out.println("Public key: " + byteArrayToString(pair.getPublic().getEncoded()));
            System.out.println("Private key: " + byteArrayToString(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded()));

            Cipher encryptPublic = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            encryptPublic.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pair.getPublic());

            Cipher decryptPublic = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            decryptPublic.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pair.getPublic());

            Cipher encryptPrivate = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            encryptPrivate.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pair.getPrivate());

            Cipher decryptPrivate = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            decryptPrivate.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pair.getPrivate());

            System.out.println("All ciphers created.");
            System.out.println();

            String plainText = "Hello World!";
            System.out.println("Plain text: " + plainText);
            String encrypted = new String(encryptPrivate.doFinal(plainText.getBytes()));
            System.out.println("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
            String decrypted = new String(decryptPublic.doFinal(encrypted.getBytes()));
            System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decrypted);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String byteArrayToString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        String str = "";

        for (byte b : bytes)
        {
            str += b + " ";
        }

        return str.trim();
    }
}
```

[And this the output (image because it doesn't let me copy the encrypted text).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUgqz.png)

Any ideas?

EDIT: Changed the following:

```
String plainText = "Hello World!";
System.out.println("Plain text: " + plainText);
String encrypted = byteToBase64String(encryptPublic.doFinal(plainText.getBytes()));
System.out.println("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
String decrypted = byteToBase64String(decryptPublic.doFinal(encrypted.getBytes()));
System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decrypted);
```

Method used to convert bytes to Base64:

```
private static String byteToBase64String(byte[] bytes)
{
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
```

But now I get this error:

```
Plain text: Hello World!
Encrypted: dCTsYrQTDfNkRr6+nupWW4ntsmD69wrWS1TDvS3Uk1B6lCKkycegAb7wJgnXNolZ58dRXgbzEyCkeM/IbH0ruIEMfuhS5vrggo1s9+6MQN2hW1I4iElJfAdGKYQ8H9pFhAws+VQGetjwvJwUI9iWIi15721vc508/ks7rn4oQOk=
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 128 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:344)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at rsa.testing.AloneTest.doTest(AloneTest.java:40)
    at rsa.testing.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Do I have to do some sort of splitting? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: You are converting `byte[]` to `String` without properly encoding it - THIS WILL NOT WORK. Instead use base64 for converting `byte[]` to `String`!

Comment: I added conversion to Base64, but now I get a new error that can be seen in my post.

Comment: Of course you have to base64 decode the data before decrypting. Note that my first comment only applies to byte[] values that contain binary data for byte[] that contains textual data you can convert it directly to String.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I agree with @Robert: You should **work always only with `byte[]`**, and only convert to String (through base64, or direct converting, or whatever) just when you want to transfer the crypted data through some text means (lik `System.out`).

Comment: plaintext string -> char encode to byte[] -> encrypt -> base 64 encode -> ciphertext string -> base 64 decode -> decrypt -> character decode to string -> plaintext string

Comment: Note that often there is not need in crypto to convert anything from / to strings. Doing so is the crypto equivalent of stringly typed code (look it up). Modern cryptography operates on bits / bytes, so if you can store binary data then there is no need to convert to strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing this:

when encrypting with *public key* one should use *private key* to decrypt
and also
when encrypting with *private key* one should use *public key* to decrypt

**UPDATE**

When encrypting with e.g. *private key* then trying to decrypt with *same* private key you'll have that *java.crypto.BadPaddingException*

I can't share the code proving this but I tested using:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGen.initialize(2048);
keyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
```

while for Cipher I used:

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
```

Comment: My question is pretty old so I already figured that out a while ago. Thanks for answering though :)

Comment: I had few moments ago the same annoying problem and seeing yous not answered I thought it's a java bug :D.